# How to ingest data from two producers in kafka and join using spark structured streaming?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from two `kafka` topics, but I am unable to join and find teh final dataframe.
My kafka topics are CSVStreamRetail and OrderItems.

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Spark-Stream-Example")
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")
      .getOrCreate()

    val ordersSchema = new StructType()
      .add("order_id", IntegerType)
      .add("order_date", StringType)
      .add("order_customer_id", IntegerType)
      .add("order_status", StringType)

    val orderItemsSchema = new StructType()
      .add("order_item_id",IntegerType)
      .add("order_item_order_id",IntegerType)
      .add("order_item_product_id",IntegerType)
      .add("order_item_quantity",IntegerType)
      .add("order_item_subtotal",DoubleType)
      .add("order_item_product_price", DoubleType)

    import spark.implicits._

    val df1 = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "CSVStreamRetail")
      .load()

    val df2 = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "OrderItems")
      .load()

    val ordersDF = df1.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)").as[(String,Timestamp)]
      .select(from_json($"value", ordersSchema).as("orders_data"),$"timestamp")
      .select("orders_data.*","timestamp")

    val orderItemsDF = df2.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)").as[(String,Timestamp)]
      .select(from_json($"value",orderItemsSchema).as("order_items_data"),$"timestamp")
      .select("order_items_data.*","timestamp")

    val finalDF = orderItemsDF.join(ordersDF, orderItemsDF("order_item_order_id")===ordersDF("order_id"))

    finalDF
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

The output I am receiving is an empty dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please check whether you are receiving data in your `kafka` topics.
You should always provide watermarking at least in one stream in case of a stream-stream join. I see you want to perform an inner join.
So I have added `200 seconds` watermarking and now it is showing data in the output dataframe.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("Spark-Stream-Example")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp")
  .getOrCreate()

val ordersSchema = new StructType()
  .add("order_id", IntegerType)
  .add("order_date", StringType)
  .add("order_customer_id", IntegerType)
  .add("order_status", StringType)

val orderItemsSchema = new StructType()
  .add("order_item_id",IntegerType)
  .add("order_item_order_id",IntegerType)
  .add("order_item_product_id",IntegerType)
  .add("order_item_quantity",IntegerType)
  .add("order_item_subtotal",DoubleType)
  .add("order_item_product_price", DoubleType)

import spark.implicits._

val df1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "CSVStreamRetail")
  .load()

val df2 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "OrderItems")
  .load()

val ordersDF = df1.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)").as[(String,Timestamp)]
  .select(from_json($"value", ordersSchema).as("orders_data"),$"timestamp")
  .select("orders_data.*","timestamp")
  .withWatermark("timestamp","200 seconds")

val orderItemsDF = df2.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)").as[(String,Timestamp)]
  .select(from_json($"value",orderItemsSchema).as("order_items_data"),$"timestamp")
  .select("order_items_data.*","timestamp")
  .withWatermark("timestamp","200 seconds")

val finalDF = orderItemsDF.join(ordersDF, orderItemsDF("order_item_order_id")===ordersDF("order_id"))

finalDF
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Use the eventTimestamp for joining.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I do know that joining two streaming datasets watermarking and time constraint is optional. If watermark and time constraints are not specified then data is stored in the state indefinitely. Setting watermark on both sides and time constraint will enable state cleanup accordingly.

Comment: @SambhavKumar Thank You. It is working now. I am now also specifying a select expression based on the timestamp.